# XSLFHyperLink not working after PPTX is encoded into Base64

Tags: hyperlink, base64, apache-poi

I have some html content which I'm inserting into a pptx slide and persisting the formatting.
I'm using apache POI for this. A base64 gets generated which I later convert to pptx. Up until now I haven't faced any issues. But now hyperlinks are causing problems.

When I just create the hyperlink with method createHyperlink(), it works fine and the PPT gets generated but the link is not set so it doesn't do any action when clicked.
When I set the URL either through setAddress() or linkToUrl() methods, the PPT generated seems corrupted and windows asks me if it can "repair" it. After the repair option, when the PPT opens, the link does not work.
Below is the code I wrote:

Approach 1:
textRun.createHyperlink();
textRun.getHyperlink().linkToUrl("http://poi.apache.org");

Approach 2:
textRun.createHyperlink();
textRun.getHyperlink().setAddress("http://poi.apache.org");

Approach 3:
XSLFHyperlink link = textRun.createHyperlink();
link.setAddress("http://poi.apache.org");

Approach 4:
XSLFHyperlink link = textRun.createHyperlink();
link.linkToUrl("http://poi.apache.org");

None of these approaches work.
Does anyone have any idea regarding this and provide me the right solution?

**Update 1:**
So after analyzing the issue, I realized the issue is not with XSLFHyperlink, but with the final Base64 String encoding of the PPTX which I then pass to the UI front-end.
I'm using org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 for encoding and decoding of the base64 string.
I tried using encodeBase64String and encodeBase64URLSafeString methods.
Both don't maintain the URL and distort it.

If anyone has any clues, please help

**Update 2**
Issue resolved now :) Thank you

Comment: How exactly are you encoding a `XMLSlideShow` into a Base64 String and vice versa? Please provide code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear where your problem is. For me `XSLFHyperlink.setAddress` as well as `XSLFHyperlink.linkToUrl` are working and create usable hyperlinks using current Apache POI version 5.2.3.

Complete example:

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.*;

import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class CreatePPTXTextShapeWithLinkedText {
    
 static XSLFTextParagraph drawRectWithText(XSLFSlide slide, int x, int y, int width, int height, String text) {
  XSLFAutoShape shape = slide.createAutoShape();
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
  shape.setAnchor(rect.getBounds2D());
  shape.setShapeType(ShapeType.RECT);
  shape.setText(text);
  shape.setTextDirection(TextShape.TextDirection.HORIZONTAL);
  shape.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);
  
  XSLFTextParagraph xslfTextParagraph = shape.getTextParagraphs().get(0);
  xslfTextParagraph.setTextAlign(TextParagraph.TextAlign.CENTER);
  return xslfTextParagraph;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  SlideShow slideShow = new XMLSlideShow();

  XSLFSlide slide = (XSLFSlide)slideShow.createSlide();

  XSLFTextParagraph xslfTextParagraph = drawRectWithText(slide, 100, 100, 500, 50, "This is a test text. ");
  
  XSLFTextRun xslfTextRun = xslfTextParagraph.addNewTextRun();
  xslfTextRun.setText("This text is linked to Apache POI.");
  XSLFHyperlink xslfHyperlink = xslfTextRun.createHyperlink();
  xslfHyperlink.setAddress("http://poi.apache.org");
  
  xslfTextRun = xslfTextParagraph.addNewTextRun();
  xslfTextRun.setText(" This is a test text again. ");
  
  xslfTextRun = xslfTextParagraph.addNewTextRun();
  xslfTextRun.setText("This text is linked to Stackoverflow.");
  xslfHyperlink = xslfTextRun.createHyperlink();
  xslfHyperlink.linkToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");

  xslfTextRun = xslfTextParagraph.addNewTextRun();
  xslfTextRun.setText(" This is a test text again. ");
  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreatePPTXTextShapeWithLinkedText.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
  slideShow.close();
 }
}
```

It creates:

[image]

Note: To open a hyperlink while editing a presentation, right-click the hyperlink and select **Open Hyperlink** on the shortcut menu. Only  during a slide show hyperlinks will work as you might think they should. See [Open a hyperlink](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-a-hyperlink-0c8d9839-e49c-461f-b6d9-49df0ce2c079). But that's by design in PowerPoint.

---

Still not clear where exactly your problem is. Because if I do the following using my code from above:

```java
...
/*  
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreatePPTXTextShapeWithLinkedText.pptx");
  slideShow.write(out);
  out.close();
*/

  // create Base64 encoded String from SlideShow
  java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
  slideShow.write(byteOut);
  slideShow.close();
  byte[] slideShowBytes = byteOut.toByteArray();
  String base64Encoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(slideShowBytes);
  
  // write Base64 encoded String to a text file
  java.io.FileOutputStream base64EncodedOut = new java.io.FileOutputStream("./CreatePPTXTextShapeWithLinkedTextBase64.txt");
  byte[] strToBytes = base64Encoded.getBytes();
  base64EncodedOut.write(strToBytes);
  base64EncodedOut.close();
  
  // read Base64 encoded bytes from the text file
  java.io.File base64EncodedFile = new java.io.File("./CreatePPTXTextShapeWithLinkedTextBase64.txt");
  java.io.FileInputStream base64EncodedIn = new java.io.FileInputStream(base64EncodedFile);
  byte[] base64EncodedBytes = new byte[(int)base64EncodedFile.length()];
  base64EncodedIn.read(base64EncodedBytes);
  base64EncodedIn.close();
  
  // get decoded bytes
  byte[] slideShowBytesDecoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(base64EncodedBytes);
  
  // write decoded bytes to the *.pptx file
  java.io.FileOutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream("./CreatePPTXTextShapeWithLinkedText.pptx");
  out.write(slideShowBytesDecoded);
  out.close(); 
...
```

The resulting `CreatePPTXTextShapeWithLinkedText.pptx` is proper readable by PowerPoint and the links are working too.

Comment: Alright I realized the issue now, its not the XSLFHyperlink, but the final base64 encoding that I'm doing which is distorting the hyperlink that was set.
Again, if anyone has any idea regarding this, please help out

Comment: So turns out the issue was with the byte array encoding that i was doing in the end. Its been working fine since i rectified it. Thank you :)